# How to get record details of a DNS record via aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I want to get the details of a DNS record in AWS route53.

What is the aws cli command to get DNS record details given that we have the domain name or the record ID?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [list-resource-record-set](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html) command.

You can filter to a specific record using `--query`, as seen in example below.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z2LD58HEXAMPLE --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == 'example.domain.']"
```

Alternatively if you just need resolution information take a look at running DIG.

Comment: DON't forget the `.` at the end.